# usinig Django urls in react, is_authenticated in react, displaying context in react

Tags: django, reactjs, django-views, react-router

So, I've got 3 questions

> 1. How to use Django's URLs in react

***EXAMPLE:***

**index.js (in react)**

```
<Router>
        <div>
                <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
                    <div className="container">
                        <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">PetFinder</Link>
                        <Link to="/storage" className="navbar-brand">Storage </Link>
                        <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign-Up</a>  <== like this
                    </div>
                </nav>
                  <Route exact path={"/"} component={PetRegistration} />
                  <Route path={"/storage"}  render={() => <Storage ids={checkingName} />} />
       </div>
</Router>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace="rest_framework")),
    path('api/animals/', include('petsite.urls', namespace='petsite')),
    path('api/user_info', core_views.UserInfo.as_view()),
    path('signup/', core_views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('', csrf_exempt(core_views.index), name='index'),
    path(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),

]
```

> 2. is_authenticated in react

How I did it:

**In index.html**

I wrote this ******. I am ashamed of this. Don't judge me, okay just a bit...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">


    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div class="signUpBlock">
      <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign-Up</a>
    </div>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <span class="currentUser"     style="display: none">{{user.id}}</span>
    <span class="currentUserName" style="display: none">{{user.username}}</span>
    <span id="DJANGO_USER"        style="display: none"></span>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var WHETHER_DJANGO_USER_IS_AUTH = "{{user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true,false"}}";
   document.getElementById("DJANGO_USER").innerHTML = WHETHER_DJANGO_USER_IS_AUTH;
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Check the code below:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var WHETHER_DJANGO_USER_IS_AUTH = "{{user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true,false"}}";
   document.getElementById("DJANGO_USER").innerHTML = WHETHER_DJANGO_USER_IS_AUTH;
</script>

<span id="DJANGO_USER"        style="display: none"></span>
```

**AND THEN IN index.js I do this**

```
let boolButString = $('#DJANGO_USER').text()
var StringToBool = (boolButString === 'true');
```

If StringToBool = true I do smth (means that user is logged in)

else StringToBool != true I do smth (means that user is not logged in)

```
if (StringToBool) {
 do smth
} else {
 make some tea for him
}
```

*I don't think I did it in a right way can you suggest me smth?*

*Is it real to check whether a user is auth. or not?*

> 3. How to display Django context in react.

You might have seen how I did it in index.html 
As usual, I wrote:

```
 def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html', {

        "user"     : request.user,

})
```

end then

```
    <span class="currentUser"     style="display: none">{{user.id}}</span>
```

grab data through jquery and display it in react app.

What can you suggest me?
How to display context properly?

Sry for cups.

Comment: React is SPA, meaning when your url changes, react doesn't communicate with thy server if you manually don't do it.

Comment: How can I do it manually? Is it good to do it manually?

Comment: You should update your content from the place when react finishes loading to be able to see `is_authenticated`.

Comment: Why do you need to do it manually? React is supposed to render html for you, you're trying to fetch it from the server. If you want to render html from the server, you need to execute XHR and set component's data from that xhr/

Comment: I have signup template on the server (Django) and URLs to it. And in react I just want to use this URL to navigate a user to this template

Comment: SO I CAN JUST DO THIS IN MY index.js? In my header  I can add       `<a href="/signup">Sign-Up</a>` - I did it and it works, but I don't know is it right ?